# Extract numbers from a string of fixed format in Java

Tags: java

I have a string of format :

```
"A hr B min to C hr D min"
```

where A, B, C, D will be integers. I want to extract A, B, C, D from this string. A, B, C, D can be single or multi digit integers and I am not really concerned with validation right now (such as C, D would be between 0 and 59 ideally) as that can be taken care of later.

What is the best way to achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this text could appear inside a larger text, and that your target phrase might be repeated more than once, we can try matching on the following pattern:

```regex
\b(\d+) hr (\d+) min to (\d+) hr (\d+) min\b
```

Here is a sample Java code:

```java
String input = "blah blah 1 hr 5 min to 2 hr 10 min blah blah";
String regex = "\\b(\\d+) hr (\\d+) min to (\\d+) hr (\\d+) min\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found values: (" + m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ", " +
        m.group(3) + ", " + m.group(4) + ")");
}
```

This prints:

```
Found values: (1, 5, 2, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class splitString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String hours = "5 hr 6 min to 17 hr 09 min";
    
    String[] splithours = hours.split(" ");
    
    for(String splitted: splithours) {
        if(splitted.matches("[0-9]{2}") || splitted.matches("[0-9]") ) {
            System.out.println(splitted);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Running code]